# In event-APIs of Javascript (like DOM), when do the setters for properties which have a corresponding change event do themselves trigger this event?

Tags: javascript, events, setter

Note that "setter" is meant in the broader sense, i.e. any method that does set or change a certain property.
Likewise "change event" is meant in the broader sense, i.e. an event that indicates that a certain property has changed.

I'm struggling to understand if there is a certain logic, according to which in Javascript events are sometimes fired when a setter is called programmatically and sometimes not.

**Examples  of setters that don't  fire a corresponding change event** (for them those events are only fired with user-interaction):

- `<input>`-tags, `<select>`-tags and `<textarea>`-tags:
  programmatically setting `tag.value = newValue` does **not** fire a 'change'-event
- `history.pushState()`  changes `history.state` but the corresponding 'popstate'-event is **not** fired

**Examples of setters that do fire a corresponding change Event:**

- 'hashchange' is fired even when set programatically with `document.location.hash='#x=y'`
- 'resize' is fired even when the window size of a popup window is set programmatically via `win.resizeTo(x, y)`
- `<video>` and `<audio>`-tags: `video.currentTime = newValue;` does fire a 'timeupdate'-Event
- `video.pause()` (as a setter for property `video.paused`) does fire a 'paused'-event.

(I've tested these with Firefox 104)

I understand the **logic of not firing an event (i.e. the first group)** as follows:
If we set a property ourselves programmatically, then we know that it has changed, so there is no need for an event. There are situations where it can be practical, but it is not necessary. It could even cause harm. Imagine, we have two `<input>` fields with a different `step`attribute (e.g of type `ruler`) synchronized by listening to each other's change event. When the first changes by user interaction and fires a
change event, we adapt the second with its setter. If that setter would fire a change event again, the first would listen to it. With different steps this can lead to an infinite ping-pong.
According to this reasoning, the rule should be that an event should be fired only when there is some input from the exterior world.
(Maybe in functional programming language one could pin it down to an I/O Monad)

For the **second group** I recognize that there are some setters that might not be successful or at least not immediately. E.g. `window.resizeTo()` succeds only, if the window was opened by us.
Also the setter for `video.currentTime` might not be successful, e.g. if the video is not yet loaded. So in these cases an event could seem necessary, to tell us if and when the setting succeeded.
But the setting of document.location.hash seems immediate to me (no Http-Request needed), so why an Event here?
And also for `video.pause()` I don't understand the event, as it (in contrast to `video.play()`) does **not** return a `Promise` and is supposed to be immediate and always successful.

The information which setters induce change-events and which don't is not easily available (at least I didn't find e.g. the information about the fact that setters for input fields don't induce a change event
on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#events), but was testing myself).
Therefore I'm looking for a rule of thumb. So I'm curious to hear if there is more to it than the two reasonings I've sketched above. This would also be useful when creating own objects (e.g. custom-html elements) and having to decide, whether to throw an event in a setter or not.

**Remark 1:** As a reaction to comments, I would like to stress that I am of course aware that one can find the information for each event somewhere in the specs or on MDN. Just sometimes not as prominently as I would have expected.  It was not my main concern to get this information in a particular case, but I was more looking for the logic behind the different behavior, in order to get a rule of thumb or alternatively an overview if it already existed. Nevertheless some provided links and comments were already very helpful and I'm going to write an own answer, which I would be happy to turn into a community wiki, if there is interest to turn it into such an overview.

**Remark 2:** My original title was asking for "native Javascript". My intention was to not ask about arbitrary libraries like Jquery, but to restrict to officially specified Javascript APIs. However, I was informed in the comments that "native" is not the proper word, in particular as all my examples apparently were about the DOM API while native Javascript has nothing like a DOM.

Comment: What you call "native JavaScript" seems to be exclusively browser-based DOM API, *not* JavaScript specifically. JavaScript itself is not directly involved in the events being issued. That is defined by the HTML specs, e.g., https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement

Comment: in general you should just check the doc about the given event.. for example the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) where it's clearly stated that: _"The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when the user modifies the element's value. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value."_ and goes further with details. Anyway in general if your logic depends on events occurring on elements, just send the event to fire the corresponding logic

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for the remark. So you would recommend a different title? However, I would be interested also in other 'change' events, not related to the dom, but didn't have examples. So please feel free to contribute some non-DOM examples!

Comment: Any other change events would depend on when and how they are issued. There is no way to generalise over completely unrelated APIs and libraries.

Comment: @Sebastian - The point is that JavaScript, itself, doesn't have events **at all**. Only APIs exposed to JavaScript by other things (like the DOM, or Node.js's file I/O, or ...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and VLAZ . Ok, thanks, I have changed the title. Hope that's better.

Comment: @diegod thanks, it is true that your link clearly states when it fires. In the specs however, the info is not with the Events but with the element (VLAZ's link). At the very end of this [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events) there is this note: "These events are not fired in response to changes made to the values of form controls by scripts. (This is to make it easier to update the values of form controls in response to the user manipulating the controls, without having to then filter out the script's own changes to avoid an infinite loop.)"

Comment: @diegod in fact I still think that the information on Mozilla is misleading or partly wrong, because also the 'input'-event does **not** fire (Firefox & Chrome) when setting the value programmatically. While your link and in particular the page for [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-events suggest that it does:  "The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed." The previously linked spec is fortunately more precise here.

Comment: @sebastian I just reported the exact phrase from the link saying that the event gets fired when the user changed the value. You insist on the programmatically event but that’s not how it works. It’s your own invention. If you want the change event to fire when you change the .value prop you have to fire the event programmatically as well. That’s an UI thing that requires user interaction. Please take the time to read something before saying it’s misleading or wrong. I even pasted that sentence alone and you didn’t need to click any link

Comment: @diegod Maybe you didn't properly read my original post. It is by no means my invention that some setters trigger their own events (yes programmatically). It's not that I like them to do so. Some do, others don't. For those that do (like the setter for document.location.hash), the wording of Mozilla's description is almost exactly the same as for the 'input' event for `<input>` field, yet they behave differently.
"The hashchange event is fired when the fragment identifier of the URL has changed". 
I don't doubt your link on the change-event, but the one on the closely related 'input'-event.

Comment: @diegod if `location.hash` would behave the same as `input.value`, it would fire an event only if the user changes the hash in the browser. But instead, even if one sets programmatically `location.hash = newLocation`, the corresponding change event does fire. This is different for the 'input' event, yet their descriptions at MDN read almost the same.

Comment: @Sebastian When you replied specifically to me I was expecting you talking about my point made yesterday talking exclusively about the change event fired on input elements. The [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) I shared says clearly that the change event is fired when _"the user modifies the element's value_". It would be misleading or wrong only if you needed a further explanation that doing `.value =` is not a user interaction. But you already knew those things since you were aware in your question.

Comment: The input event behaves as well and in the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) is described as _"when the user modifies the element's value"_.

Comment: Now talking about events not fired on input elements like hashchange or resize. [hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) _"The hashchange event is fired when the fragment identifier of the URL has changed."_ And you judge that saying _"yet their descriptions at MDN read almost the same."_ I don't agree. You don't read anywhere there that ***the user*** changed the value. The subject firing the event is the window object and that's true also for resize.

Comment: It's hard to make a rule of thumb but in general I would just pay more attention on details. Most of the events fired by the browser it's a way to connect user interaction made on the UI with DOM. But it's important to stress out that the mdn documentation is very hardly wrong.

Comment: errata: I was wrong about the input event description.. it doesn't involve the user as explicitely as it does on the change event. Maybe the fact he is talking about controls in terms of html tags could almost excuses it ... but really it's a matter of splitting the hair. In the [html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input) is described better.

Comment: @diegod I guess you got my very first comment to you wrong. I had even upvoted it and fully agreed with it. I was only mentioning that the same information is at a different place in the specs. Only then I realized that the description of the 'input' event (not the 'change' event) was misleading and added this as an extra comment. That was all the misunderstanding between us. All good.

Comment: I didn't get that part correctly back then.. I think we cleared our misunderstanding in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edits to make this community-wiki answer more complete or more correct  are explicitly encouraged. The answer so far is intentionally quite redundant to the question, because the question was giving part of the answer. This should enable future editors to modify the existing reasoning where necessary.

The examples listed in the OP's question are exclusively events of the DOM API based on the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface. It was stressed in comments that one cannot generalize over arbitrary APIs nor even over different cases within one API. Nevertheless there are certainly common reasons shared by many different use cases for either triggering an event in a setter or not. This doesn't mean that there won't be many exceptions to a rule of thumb.

**Main reason(s) for NOT triggering an event in a setter**
The first example of the question for this group ('change'-events of `<input>`-tags, `<select>`-tags and `<textarea>`-tags) happens to have an explicit reasoning in the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events):

> These events are not fired in response to changes made to the values of form controls by scripts. (This is to make it easier to update the values of form controls in response to the user manipulating the controls, without having to then filter out the script's own changes to avoid an infinite loop.)

This is similar to what was suspected in the OP's question.
The same reasoning applies to all kind of synchronization between different objects. So therefore the other group should have more important reasons to overrule this one.

**Main reason(s) for triggering an event in a setter**
Maybe future edits will provide some official reference here.
Clearly setters whose setting is not immediate and might even fail, **do need** to trigger an event, in order for the programmer to obtain the information if and when the requested change indeed happened. Not all of the examples for this group in the OP's question are of this kind. In particular for `location.hash` the event seems unnecessary.

Note that for all the original examples of this group, even those where a setting seems immediately possible (like `location.hash`), the setters do **not** dispatch the event **immediately** in the same call stack (this was found only empirically with Firefox 104 and Chrome 105, therefore references for non-obvious cases like `hash` would be appreciated). Thus the program flow in

```
object.property = newValue;
doNextThing();
```

will not be interrupted by the event handler. (It would, if the setter would directly, i.e. without timeout, call `object.dispatchEvent(new Event('propertychange'))`). The programmatic change in `hash` does however immediately dispatch a 'popstate' event (which otherwise was considered to belong to the other group).

In spite of the above fact, even for maybe non-succeeding setter-calls like `video.currentTime = newTime` or `video.play()` the new value of the corresponding property is set **immediately**, meaning `console.log(video.currentTime)` and `console.log(video.paused)` directly after the setting will already give the new values. This can  sometimes be long before the corresponding event (again found empirically). A notable exception (for Firefox, not for Chrome) seems to be `window.resizeTo()`, where for Firefox the new value is set only after succesfull resizing and shortly before the event.

This would have allowed in principle also for this group a behavior where the setter itself doesn't trigger any event, and dispatching an event is reserved for the case were the setting turns out to be impossible and is turned back at a later time. This is however not the way it is. It is therefore hard to give a convincing reasoning why this second group *has to behave differently* than the first.

**Edit:** in the [html specs about navigating](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate-non-frag-sync) there is a statement about "web-developer sadness" related to the behavior of the popstate event in contrast to the hashchange event. This links to a new [history-event proposal](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5562) containing reasons of why emitting an event in the setter is useful.

The following lists of examples contain the examples of the OP's question, but in addition refer to the official references and ideally will be growing over time to maybe provide a useful overview in the future.<sup>1</sup>

**Examples  of setters that do NOT  trigger a corresponding change event**

Events of this group are only fired with user-interaction. If no explicit setter is mentioned, the implicit setter of the property is meant.

| type of object | property | explicit setter | event | remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<input>`-tags, `<select>`-tags and `<textarea>`-tags | `value` |  | ['change'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) or ['input'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)<sup>2</sup> | [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events) for the input-element are most specific about the reason |
| `history` | `state` | `pushState()` | ['popstate'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) | "Fired at the Window when the user navigates the session history" ([specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-popstate)) |

**Examples of setters that DO trigger a corresponding change event:**

Events of this group are fired even when the value of the property is set programmatically. If no explicit setter is mentioned, the implicit setter of the property is meant.

| type of object | property | explicit setter | event | remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Window` instances | `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` | `resizeTo(x,y)` | ['resize'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) | -- |
| `document.location` | `hash` |  | ['hashchange'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) | the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface) of `Location` have an interesting warning |
| `<video>` and `<audio>`-tags | `currentTime` |  | ['timeupdate'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) | [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-timeupdate) |
| -"- | `volume` and `muted` |  | ['volumechange'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volumechange_event) |  |
| -"- | `playbackRate` |  | ['ratechange'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ratechange_event) |  |
| -"- | `paused` | `pause()` and `play()` | ['pause'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause_event) and ['play'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) |  |
| `<input>`-tags and `<textarea>`-tags | `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` |  | ['selectionchange'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/selectionchange_event) | this is still an experimental feature, but notable, as it is on the same elements as the major examples for the non-triggering group |

[1] The idea is not to get an exhaustive list - probably almost every event can be seen as a change-event for some property - but to have a sufficiently large list to cover common use cases and see if they are explained by the reasoning given so far. One can search for events that are in a broad sense change events e.g. in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#event_listing) or [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#events-2) list of events.  When there is only one reference for a particular reference given in the table, it is usually to MDN, because from there one easily gets to the specs, but not always the other way round.

[2] The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) page for input' events is a bit misleading, stating only

> The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed

not making clear that this change has to be user-induced. In the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input) for this event it is instead clear

> Fired when the user changes the contenteditable element's content, or the form control's value

and in the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events) for the `<input>` element, it is even stressed that it is not fired when set programmatically, as cited already above in the "reasons"-section.