# Programmatically setting the date input's value in a change event handler triggers change event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to render an error whenever someone chooses a date that is off day (like Saturday or Sunday, it may be any one of the day from an array of closing days).

I have HTML:

```html
<div>
  <input type="date" id="date-input">
</div>

<br>

<div id="error-container">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.d-error{
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
'use strict';

const dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input');
const errorContainer = document.getElementById('error-container');
const closingDays = [0, 6];
const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday'];

const displayError = function ({ parentEl, message, position = 'prepend', durationSec = 0 }) {
  const errorElement = document.createElement('p');
  errorElement.classList.add('d-error');
  errorElement.textContent = message;
  parentEl[position](errorElement);

  if (durationSec) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorElement.remove();
    }, durationSec * 1000);
  }
};

const handleDateChange = function (event) {
  const selectedDay = new Date(event.currentTarget.value).getDay();

  if (closingDays.includes(selectedDay)) {
    displayError({
      parentEl: errorContainer,
      message: `We are closed on ${weekDays[selectedDay]}. Please select another day.`,
      durationSec: 5
    });

    event.currentTarget.value = '';
  }
};

dateInput.addEventListener('change', handleDateChange);
```

This works, but the error is rendered twice. Once due to user change and once due to programmatically changing the value of the input `event.currentTarget.value = '';`. So, how to temporarily remove the `change` event listener and reattach to it? Or any other way to solve this issue?

I tried:

```js
const handleDateChange = function(event) {
  ...

  event.currentTarget.removeEventListener('change', handleDateChange);
  event.currentTarget.value = '';  
  event.currentTarget.addEventListener('change', handleDateChange);

  ...
}
```

But this did not fix the issue.

### Update:

Firstly, as pointed out by @Sebastian, programmatically setting the input's value **does not trigger a `change` event**. So there must be something else that is causing the event to trigger twice.

I am extremely sorry for not testing out in other browsers other than Firefox. The issue seems to only be in Firefox as in chromium based browser, everything works as expected (works in Firefox android though). So, I am guessing it is some kind of bug in Firefox, which I alone cannot confirm. Please try running the code snippet in different browsers.

```js
'use strict';

const dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input');
const errorContainer = document.getElementById('error-container');
const closingDays = [0, 6];
const weekDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

const displayError = function({
  parentEl,
  message,
  position = 'prepend',
  durationSec = 0
}) {
  const errorElement = document.createElement('p');
  errorElement.classList.add('d-error');
  errorElement.textContent = message;
  parentEl[position](errorElement);

  if (durationSec) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorElement.remove();
    }, durationSec * 1000);
  }
};

const handleDateChange = function(event) {
  const selectedDay = new Date(event.currentTarget.value).getDay();

  if (closingDays.includes(selectedDay)) {
    displayError({
      parentEl: errorContainer,
      message: `We are closed on ${weekDays[selectedDay]}. Please select another day.`,
      durationSec: 5
    });

    event.currentTarget.value = '';
  }
};

dateInput.addEventListener('change', handleDateChange);
```

```css
.d-error {
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="date" id="date-input">
</div>

<br>

<div id="error-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Disabling a listener is probably not the right strategy. I'd use data to determine whether the message should be displayed. Check a value, be it the date or a Boolean variable controlling messaging.

Comment: Perhaps, rather than resetting the input value, you style it as "invalid" and don't let them move on until it's valid. A boolean could help control that.

Comment: @isherwood How would you exactly do that? Wrapping `if (event.currentTarget.value !== '')` to `displayError()` is still rendering error twice. Also tried this condition `if (new Date(event.currentTarget.value).getDay() || new Date(event.currentTarget.value).getDay() === 0)`, still I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: programmatically setting the input value should not trigger a change-event for the input field. See e.g. [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73762118/15983216) . So I guess there is a different reason that you get the event twice.

Comment: @Sebastian Interesting, yes indeed, the change event is not triggered for programmatically setting the input's value. Also, I did not test in other browser than Firefox, in chromium based browsers like Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge, it is working as expected, so double trigger is only happening in Firefox (but not happening in Firefox android). So, is it a bug in Firefox? Can't confirm alone.

Comment: Mobile Chrome here, it's only updating after picking a second time. First pick gets no change, even if it's Saturday or Sunday. Second pick gets it to complain. Also not changing the day it complains about, e.g. getting stuck on Saturday even after picking Sunday multiple times in a row.

Comment: This is called an XY problem - Asking for the solution to Y because it is believed to solve the original problem X. Better off solving the original issue rather than creating confusion and possibly more issues.

Comment: @AayushKarna indeed, it happens in Firefox (for me 121) and not in Chromium (for me 121). Seems to really be a browser bug, if we don't overlook some racing condition between the different browsers here. But I don't see, where firing a second event could be justified ...

Comment: @l3l_aze Different browsers should not behave differently, that is the reason we have specs. I think creating confusion due to the inconsistent behavior in different browser is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shorter Version of the snippet to reproduce the bug in Firefox (121). The OP was right that the second event is really somehow caused by programmatically setting the value of the input field inside the event handler (and this should not be the case, according to the first note [here in the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events)). However, the value printed to the console in the second event is identical to the value of the first event. Furthermore setting the value outside the event handler does not trigger the event at all (as it should be). In the meantime this inconsistent behavior was reported by the OP [here on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1881419) (it might be related to [this other one](https://bugzil.la/1694413)).

```js
function onChange(event) {
  console.log('changed to ' + dateInput.value)
  dateInput.value = ''; // somehow triggers a second event in Firefox
};

dateInput.addEventListener('change', onChange);
dateInput.value = '2024-02-07'; // does not trigger the event!
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="date" id="dateInput">
</div>
```

Other browsers seem to be fine. In particular Chromium 121 behaves as expected (only one Event).
As a workaround for Firefox, the OP's attempt was not far from working. It turns out, that the following works for not listening to the second event (though see better solution below)

```
dateInput.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
dateInput.value = ''; // somehow triggers a second event
setTimeout(() => dateInput.addEventListener('change', onChange), 0);
```

It seems that the extra event is not dispatched immediately by Firefox  (so not within the same call stack). Therefore adding a timeout before re-attaching the listener helps. Code might be more transparent and performant though, if you use a boolean flag, as suggested by @isherwood.

As noted in the comments by @AayushKarna , the visible feedback of resetting the input field in the event handler is still missing in Firefox. Therefore, it also has to be set with an extra timeout. But then it doesn't trigger an event in Firefox anymore, so that removing the event-listener becomes superflous. I still leave the above suggestion in the answer, because it was explicitly asked for in the question. Nevertheless, the much simpler workaround-snippet is now:

```js
function onChange(event) {
  console.log('changed to ' + dateInput.value)
  setTimeout(() => dateInput.value = '', 0);
};

dateInput.addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="date" id="dateInput">
</div>
```

Even in Firefox, the value of the change is then printed only once and the input field is also visibly reset.

**Update:** Apparently (according to the bug report) the bug will be fixed in Version **125** of Firefox. Note that the above workaround for prior Versions has still its shortcomings (see comment of @Kaiido below)

Comment: Works great, but `dateInput.value = '';` does not reset the form visually, but upon console logging its value inside the handler it prints empty string, but then when I try to access its value directly from the console then it prints actual date. It is really a weird behavior in Firefox. But putting it inside the timeout fixes it: `setTimeout(() => {dateInput.value = ''; dateInput.addEventListener('change', onChange}), 0);`.

Comment: ah, good idea! setting the value with a timeout actually makes removing and re-attaching the event-Listener completely superflous! I'll edit the answer

Comment: The issue with the second workaround is that if another listener is added it won't read the updated value.

Comment: true @Kaiido , thanks for the comment. That makes it hard to make a general workaround, apart from adding a timeout in every event-handler... But it seems the bug report already received some attention. Maybe it will be fixed in near future.